# The question is how many ounces (dry material) to add to one gallon of water?

Tags: volume, unit-of-measure

The question is how many ounces (dry material) to add to one gallon of water?

Formula given was 45.5g/100ml

45.5 grams (dry)= powdered sodium carbonate

100 ml (fluid)= water

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert $100$ml $= 0.1$ liter to its equivalent value in gallons. And you need to convert $45.5$ grams $= 0.045$ kilograms to its equivalent value in pounds (then multiply the value in pounds by 16 since there are 16 ounces per pound).

For help to convert from liters to gallons, and from kilograms to pounds, see these handy [metric conversion tables](http://www.metric-conversions.org/metric-conversion-table.htm).

Then divide the value you get in ounces by the value you get in gallons, and you'll have computed the number of ounces of dry material to add to one gallon of water.

$$\dfrac{x \;\text{ ounces}}{y\;\text{ gallons}} = \;\;\text{ounces needed per gallon.}$$

Comment: my result is 3.78 pounds per gallon (1722g/3785ml). Is that correct? (FYI. I'm not kid cheating on a test. Just a homeowner trying to make a proper lolution for a water softner).

Comment: That seems high: are you sure you didn't compute 3.78 ounces per gallon?

Comment: Actually, yes, that is what 1722 g/3785 ml computes too. 3.78 pounds/per gallon. No problem with the question, and I certainly don't mind confirming your result! (It's amazing when we find ourselves needing math!)

Comment: 45.5x10=455g (which equals 16 ounces/1 pound)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I checked it a number of ways. What I meant by my last comment was that I checked your answer and computed it a number of ways, and meant to CONFIRM your result: my first comment was an intuitive reaction. But your computations are correct, given the values you provide.

Comment: 100mlx10=1000ml (which equals 33.81 fl oz).  33.81x4=135.256 oz (just over 1 gallon). 135.256x0.9463=128 oz/1 gallon. Using the same increase formula on the dry-45.5x10=455g (which equals 16 ounces/1 pound). 1lbx4x 0.9463=3.78 pounds/per gallon

Comment: Thank you for your help. Al

Comment: You're welcome, Al!